# Google Sheets Hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink

I just started to work in GS and stuck at this point with Hyperlink:

Being within the sheet "Transfers" the link works as charm, jumping to the first empty cell in row B for new input (with 12345 being sheed ID for "Transfers"):

```
=HYPERLINK("#gid=12345...&range=B"&Min(Filter( Row(B2:B); B2:B=""));"Deposit")
```

Now I tried to put that link on my main "Dashboard" sheet. But clicking the link here is not working properly, as it will jump to sheet "Transfers" but the position of first empty cell in row B is now taken from "Dashboard" sheet instead of doing this on "Transfers".

Comment: did you change the proper gid id?

Comment: Thanks! But could solve it meanwhile

Answer (score 0):

Meanwhile i found my issue. When moving the link to another sheet you need to define the destination range with sheet info as well:

=HYPERLINK("#gid=12345&range=B"&Min(Filter( Row(B2:B); B2:B=""));"Deposit")

This is how it works on the "Transfers" sheet itself.

=HYPERLINK("#gid=12345range=B"&Min(Filter( Row(Transfers!B2:B); Transfers!B2:B=""));"Deposit")

This is my now working link at "Dashboard" sheet, which is #0.